# Import error when importing Distance metric in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import the SMOTE methodology from imblearn, but I get the following error:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

ImportError: cannot import name 'DistanceMetric' from 'sklearn.metrics' (D:\Programas\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

I've tried to import it like this, but get the same error:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==1.1.0 --user
from sklearn.metrics import DistanceMetric as _DistanceMetric

ImportError: cannot import name 'DistanceMetric' from 'sklearn.metrics' (D:\Programas\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

Any other reasons this might happen and solutions?

Comment: I am able to import `DistanceMetric` using `from sklearn.metrics import DistanceMetric as _DistanceMetric` without issue. Are you sure you have sklearn-learn installed correctly? Does `import sklearn` work for you?

Comment: Perhaps obvious but, did you install scikit-learn? We don't know how you set up your environment... Unless you used conda or pip to install `imblearn` which _usually_ take care of installing the dependencies for you, you really need to check scikit-learn. Does `import sklearn.metrics` work fine?

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting same error but what the trick is after installing imblearn (!pip install imblearn) then just reset the kernal and comment(#) the install code other wise it will install many times ..  only thing after installing just reset kernal (from imblearn import under_sampling,over_sampling)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).